# Laravel Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php, laravel

I installed a fresh version of Laravel 5.7 on my server, and I see this error.  What could be the reason?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/vagrant/Code/ya3stripe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500

[image]

Edit: The answer is simple and listed below. I did not find any duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Check PHP version. Laravel 5.7 onwards required PHP 7.1.3 or later versions.